# Show for $\alpha\in S_n$, $\alpha^{-1}(123)\alpha=(xyz)$ for some $x,y,z$. How are $x,y,z$ related to $\alpha$? Generalize.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutation-cycles

I found a exercise in my textbook, but I could not come to the conclusion.The question says that demonstrate that for any $\alpha \in S_n$, there holds ${\alpha}^{-1}(123)\alpha=(xyz)$ with suitable $x,y,z$. How are $x,y,z$ related to $\alpha$? Genaralize your conclusion  ${\alpha}^{-1}(123)\alpha$.

My attempt: I wrote some $\alpha$s to see the behavior of  ${\alpha}^{-1}(123)\alpha$, but i cannot see any results. For example:

- If $\alpha=(12)$, then  ${\alpha}^{-1}(123)\alpha=(132)$.
- If $\alpha=(123)$ ,then  ${\alpha}^{-1}(123)\alpha=(123)$.
- If $\alpha=(12)(34)$ ,then  ${\alpha}^{-1}(123)\alpha=(142)$

Can you help me to see how  ${\alpha}^{-1}(123)\alpha$ is related to $\alpha$ and $(123)$?

Comment: For a more instructive example try $\alpha = (196)(27)(38)(45)$. What if you did each of those cycles individually, e.g. $\alpha=(38)$ or $\alpha=(45)$? What does that tell you?

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: Try to apply ${\alpha}^{-1}(123)\alpha$ to $\alpha^{-1}(i)$ for $1\leq i\leq 3$ and for $i>3$.

Comment: Please don't forget, after you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

What you will find is that, for any $\alpha$,

$$\alpha^{-1}(123)\alpha=(\alpha^{-1}(1)\alpha^{-1}(2)\alpha^{-1}(3)),$$

where $\alpha^{-1}(i)$ is $\alpha^{-1}$ evaluated at $i$.

Indeed, conjugation of a permutation by another permutation preserves cycle structure. This has been covered many times before on this site.

Comment: how did you come this conclusion , is it just observation

Comment: It's a well-known and very handy lemma I learned over ten years ago, @leonard. The proof is to just follow where the LHS and the RHS send the elements of the set $\{1,\dots, n\}$.

Comment: i want to learn more about it..how can i find the proof

Comment: [Have a look at this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Conjugate_Permutations_have_Same_Cycle_Type), @leonard.

Answer (score 0):

The relation is $\alpha^{-1}(xyz)\alpha=(\alpha^{-1}(x)\alpha^{-1} (y)\alpha^{-1} (z)) $.

This generalizes to $n $-cycles, and leads easily to the fact that conjugation preserves cycle structure.