# How $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are related to conjugation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutation-cycles

Let $\gamma$ and $\beta$ be permutations in $S_n$. Describe how $\gamma^{-1}\beta\gamma$  is related to $\beta$ and $\gamma$.

I dont know how to approach this question.

I know it is conjugation but how is it related to $\beta$ and $\gamma$?

Comment: conjugation sounds like a relation. You can also relate elements with similar properties, e.g. do they have the same order?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $\beta=(b_{i_1}\dots b_{i_{l_1}})(b_{i_2}\dots b_{i_{l_2}})\dots(b_{i_m}\dots b_{i_{l_m}})$ is the cyclic decomposition of $\beta$, then consider

$$(\gamma^{-1}(b_{i_1})\dots \gamma^{-1}(b_{i_{l_1}}))(\gamma^{-1}(b_{i_2})\dots\gamma^{-1}( b_{i_{l_2}}))\dots(\gamma^{-1}(b_{i_m})\dots\gamma^{-1}( b_{i_{l_m}})),$$

where $\gamma^{-1}(b)$ is $\gamma^{-1}$ evaluated at $b$.

Comment: i found this , but it is different from what you wrote https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4120891/show-for-alpha-in-s-n-alpha-1123-alpha-xyz-for-some-x-y-z-how-a

Comment: You're right. Let me edit my answer really quick, please, @kimshuyhong.

Comment: It's correct now, @kimshuyhong.

Comment: when i check over the question which in comment , i see that it does not hold for every permutation. So , i hesitate this answer

Comment: when i put random cycles , it somethimes does not hold

Comment: Put them in where, @kimshuyhong? It should work. Note that some websites, like WolframAlpha, evaluate from left to right.

Comment: for example , for $\alpha = (12)(34)$ , $\alpha^{-1} (123)\alpha=(142)$ but it is not $(\alpha^{-1}(1)(\alpha^{-1}(2)(\alpha^{-1}(3))$

Comment: You've evaluated the expression in my answer wrong, @kimshuyhong. Note that $$\beta=(b_{i_1}\dots b_{i_{l_1}})(b_{i_2}\dots b_{i_{l_2}})\dots(b_{i_m}\dots b_{i_{l_m}})$$ is the *cycle decomposition* of $\beta$; each $(b_{i_j}\dots b_{i_{l_j}})$ is a separate cycle.

Comment: To use your example, @kimshuyhong: $$\begin{align}\alpha^{-1}(123)\alpha &=(\alpha^{-1}(1)\alpha^{-1}(2)\alpha^{-1}(3))\\ &=(214)\\ &=(142).\end{align}$$

Comment: @Shaun i think it does not hold for $\gamma =(1234)$

Comment: Sure it does, @Bulbasaur. What value of $\beta$ did you try with it?

Comment: @Shaun $\beta = (123)$

Comment: Well, @Bulbasaur, we have $$\begin{align}\gamma^{-1}\beta\gamma &= (4321)(123)(1234)\\ &=(\gamma^{-1}(1)\gamma^{-1}(2)\gamma^{-1}(3))\\ &=(412)\\ &=(4321)(1342)\\ &=(124).\end{align}$$